# Java - overriding an instance field

Tags: java

I am unable to test this myself right now as my code is broken and
unable to run the test.

If you have a `final public` instance field declared in a super class `S`.

```
class S {
   public final String field = "field in super class"; 
}

class A extends S {
   public final String field = "field in sub class A"; 
}

class B extends S {
   public final String field = "field in sub class B"; 
}
```

Doing

```
System.out.println( new A().field );
```

this will print:

```
field in sub class A
```

But given a method anywhere in any code:

```
public method(S instance) {
  System.out.printlng( instance.field ); // Will compile just fine! 
}
```

What will this print if I call `method(new A())`?

Comment: *"I am unable to test this myself right now as my code is broken and unable to run the test."* Why not test it in a new, blank project?

Comment: As for the actual question, you cannot override a field, you can only shadow it with another field of the same name. Field accesses are not resolved at runtime like methods are, so the field you are accessing is determined by the compile-time type of the expression on the left of the field access, e.g. `(expr).field` depends on the compile-time type of `expr`. In your example, the compile-time type of `instance` is `S`, so it will print `S`'s field, `field in super class`.

Comment: @kaya3 i just did ... and you are right ... it becomes directly accessed when type is declared as S.

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic

Comment: Nice question. Thanks. upvote * 6. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this code:

```
public class HelloWorld{
static class S {
   public final String field = "field in super class"; 
}

static class A extends S {
   public final String field = "field in sub class A"; 
}

static class B extends S {
   public final String field = "field in sub class B"; 
}
public static void method(S instance) {
  System.out.println( instance.field ); // Will compile just fine! 
}
public void test(){
}
public static void main(String []args){
        method(new A());
     }
}
```

On codingGround and returned "field in super class".

Comment: If you think something is great, awesome and hopefully a good answer, then please *accept the answer*, momomo. I see you have not accepted any answers on your questions, including one you've posted yourself!